# Connecting Seagate Central Drive to Windows 10 laptop

Tags: networking, windows-10, nas

I have just updated my laptop to Window 10. At first I could connect with my Seagate Central NAS drive but then I got a network error message. This says check the spelling of the name (it hasn't changed) or to run diagnostics. Running this says my Internet modem is not working--but it is working fine. I can get the Seagate drive through a desktop PC also running Windows 10.

What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting through a wireless home network, make sure that all of your adapters are operating at the same frequency.  In some cases an older 2.4G wireless card will not connect with a newer 5G network, or will connect intermittently, giving you the Network Error message with the spelling/diagnose choice.  Check the network settings tab and see if you have two networks with the same name, except for the addition of -5G at the end of one of them.